# How to make dropdown navbar black?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make dropdown navbar box black, I've been looking for solution for 2 days, but still even templates from bootstrap docs doesn't work properly, I mean that dropdown box.

[image: What I'm talking about.]

Here is my html code for navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-link"><img src="/images    /logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Main </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Main </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Main </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Courses </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Help </a>
                    <a class="visible-sm-block" href="#"> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is Page hierarchy:

[image: img]

Comment: You're using `.navbar-inverse`, which should **already** be making your navbar black: http://jsfiddle.net/dwd31puz/. You've either not referenced Bootstrap correctly, are using the wrong code for your version of Boostrap (3 vs 4), or have code that is overriding the defaults with higher specificity. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, yep, you're right, but still that dropdown box is not black. See the screenshots.

Comment: Use the code in my fiddle as a starting point, and work from there; it is working as expected in the fiddle. It's also possible that you've cached an old version of your CSS. Try `CTRL` + `F5`, and also try holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon to ensure you clear your CSS cache. Then, if the problem still exists, ensure you have provided a verifiable example of the problem.

Comment: The problem is solved. I've deleted my css and everything just works fine.

Comment: Awesome; I'll write that as an answer so you can mark this question as resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correctly using `.navbar-inverse`, which should already be making your navbar black, as can be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dwd31puz)**.

There are a couple of reasons why this may not be working for you.

- You've not referenced Bootstrap correctly.
  In this case, check for errors in your F12 Developer Tools' console.
- You're using CSS for a different version of Bootstrap than the one you've loaded.
- You have code that is overriding the defaults with higher **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.
- You have cached outdated CSS. Refresh your stylesheet refrence with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking on the refresh icon to ensure you clear your CSS cache as well.

Hope this helps! :)